# How to use Azure Cosmos DB connector to write into CosmosDB?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, spark-structured-streaming

I have one simple structured streaming application and the output sink should be CosmosDB. When I call the writeStream method the error below pops up. The version of the library added to the cluster is:

```
com.microsoft.azure:azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11:1.4.1, type:Maven
```

My code is as follows:

```
val outstream = staticInputDF 
  .writeStream
  .format(classOf[CosmosDBSinkProvider].getName)
  .options(config)
  .start
  .awaitTermination
```

That leads to the error:

> command-751666472135258:74: error: overloaded method value options
> with alternatives: (options:
> java.util.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
>  (options:
> scala.collection.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
> cannot be applied to
> (com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.config.Config)

How to write to a CosmosDB collection from a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

The following code shows how to write a data frame to Cosmos DB.

```
// Write configuration

val writeConfig = Config(Map(
  "Endpoint" -> "https://doctorwho.documents.azure.com:443/",
  "Masterkey" -> "YOUR-KEY-HERE",
  "Database" -> "DepartureDelays",
  "Collection" -> "flights_fromsea",
  "Upsert" -> "true",
  "WritingBatchSize" -> "500",
  "CheckpointLocation" -> "/checkpointlocation_write1"
))

// Write to Cosmos DB from the flights DataFrame
df
.writeStream
.format(classOf[CosmosDBSinkProvider].getName)
.options(writeConfig)
.start()
```

**Reference:** [Azure Databricks Spark Connecter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/spark-connector)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that `config` is of `com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.config.Config` type, but you can only use `.options(config)` with `java.util.Map[String,String]` or `scala.collection.Map[String,String]`.

Check out the [Stream data to from Kafka to Cosmos DB](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/hdinsight-spark-scala-kafka-cosmosdb/blob/master/Stream-data-from-Kafka-to-Cosmos-DB.ipynb) notebook where they use the following `Map`:

```
val configMap = Map(
    "Endpoint" -> "YOUR_COSMOSDB_ENDPOINT",
    "Masterkey" -> "YOUR_MASTER_KEY",
    "Database" -> "kafkadata",
    // use a ';' to delimit multiple regions
    "PreferredRegions" -> "West US;",
    "Collection" -> "kafkacollection"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to write from Synapse Apache Spark to cosmosdb, below is a code that works.
You have to create a linked server connection first and do not use managed identity. Managed identity was not working.

```py
    # Write a Spark DataFrame into an Azure Cosmos DB container
    # To select a preferred list of regions in a multi-region Azure Cosmos DB account, add .option("spark.cosmos.preferredRegions", "<Region1>,<Region2>")

    YOURDATAFRAME.write.format("cosmos.oltp")\
      .option("spark.synapse.linkedService", "<enter linked service name>")\
      .option("spark.cosmos.container", "<enter container name>")\
      .mode('append')\
      .save()
```

[Write Spark DataFrame to Azure Cosmos DB container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/synapse-link/how-to-query-analytical-store-spark-3#write-spark-dataframe-to-azure-cosmos-db-container)